# Printing the second field in a file after the header.

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a scenario where the file has the following structure:

```
This is the list of all the employees and their desk numbers
Please dont exchange the chairs or drawers
Handle the furniture around with care
Name    Desk No
----    -------
Joe     445
May     560
Sue     669
```

I need to get only the desk numbers. Im thinking of using `----` as filter and print the second column after the later text. Any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A different approach:

```
$ awk 'p{print $2}$1=="----"{p=1}' file
445
560
669
```

This uses the variable `p` as a print flag (by default the value is zero). The block `print $2` will only be executed when we set `p` to a non-zero value. We set `p` after we see a line where the first field is `----`.

Comment: Interesting. Could you explain the steps? `$1=="----"` gets the line with this and then how do you print from there?

Comment: I have added an explanation @fedorqui hope this is helpful.

Comment: +1, I think it very clever way. I am always learning from your answers.

Comment: What if the length of "----" varies? How to deal with that scenario?

Comment: You could do a regexp match instead like `awk 'p{print $2}$1~/^-{4}$/{p=1}' file` and just change the `{4}` you could say four or more  like this `{4,}` if the number isn't fixed.. or just be less strict and check the line starts with a hyphen `awk 'p{print $2}$0~/^-/{p=1}' file`

Answer (score 2):

If file has always the same header (at least same number of lines), you can start printing from a specific line:

```
awk 'NR>=6 {print $2}' file_name
```

will print from line 6 till the end. Then we print just the second record.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sed implementation:

```
sed -n '/^----/,${/----/!s/[^ ]* *//p}' file.txt
```

Explanation:
From first line starting with ---- to end of file, delete 1st field, print everything else on the line.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple `grep`?

```
$ grep -o "[0-9]\+" input
445
560
669
```

Comment: Well, the OP initially titled "awk", so I guess it is wanted in this language. Then, what if the text in the header has some numbers?

Comment: @fedorqui well, the format seemed pretty fixed, and question was tagged linux, bash, shell as well so I posted an alternative

Comment: Sure! No problem, I just highligted the `awk` aspect that was in the first version of the question.

Comment: It's pretty hard to post something before @sudo_O and his (?) solutions are generally very good so alternatives are needed :-)

Comment: Haha we should create a parallel score for us human beings : )

Comment: Just saying he's (?) very very fast, Glenn Jackman is my hero when it comes to awk!

Comment: So many heros around here, I keep learning from them all the time.